# elasticsearch - index template creation error - parse exception, unknown key

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, exception, indexing, mapping

I just recently upgraded my cluster from 6.1.x to 7.9.x version. Trying to fix index templates so in that when my data is pushed in a moment after midnight, new daily index is created automatically.

Here is how I do it:

```
## create template and mapping
 
PUT http://es1:9200/_template/tmp_staging_devices_1
{
    "template": "staging-devices-*",
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 3
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "ts": {"type": "date", "format": "epoch_millis"},
            "server_ts": {"type": "date", "format": "epoch_millis"},
            "raw": {"type": "binary"}
        }
    }
}
 
## template is listed under the list of templates
 
## trying to put some data into the elasticsearch
PUT http://es1:9200/staging-devices-2020-10-20
{
    "imei": "24779610124313",
    "json": "{\"imei\":\"357796101614313\",\"ts\":1603180834000,\"values\":{\"coreMsgId\":2810,\"obdIt\":{\"distance\":0,\"distanceCombustion\":0,\"idleTime\":0,\"idleTimeCombustion\":0,\"maxSpeed\":0,\"totalEnergyCons\":0,\"totalFuelCons\":0,\"totalTime\":488,\"totalTimeCombustion\":0}}}",
    "raw": "04 00 00 32 0A 18 08 FA 15 32 13 08 00 10 00 18 00 20 00 28 E8 03 30 00 38 00 40 00 48 00 12 0F 33 35 37 37 39 36 31 30 31 36 31 34 33 31 33 18 C2 EE CE D1 CB 2E",
    "server_ts": 1603180834000,
    "ts": 1603180834000
}
 
 
## error that I get back (400 bad request)
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "unknown key [server_ts] for create index"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "unknown key [server_ts] for create index"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The only difference from the "old system" is that I removed "values"

```
{
    "template": "staging-devices*",
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "values": {
            "properties": {
                "ts": {"type": "date", "format": "epoch_millis"},
                "server_ts": {"type": "date", "format": "epoch_millis"},
                "raw": {"type": "binary"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mention the `type` and document id.

Document type `_doc` is the default in elasticsearch 7.x.

[Removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

[Index some documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index.html)

Try this (via kibana) - tested:

```
POST staging-devices-2020-10-20/_doc/1
{
    "imei": "24779610124313",
    "json": "{\"imei\":\"357796101614313\",\"ts\":1603180834000,\"values\":{\"coreMsgId\":2810,\"obdIt\":{\"distance\":0,\"distanceCombustion\":0,\"idleTime\":0,\"idleTimeCombustion\":0,\"maxSpeed\":0,\"totalEnergyCons\":0,\"totalFuelCons\":0,\"totalTime\":488,\"totalTimeCombustion\":0}}}",
    "raw": "04 00 00 32 0A 18 08 FA 15 32 13 08 00 10 00 18 00 20 00 28 E8 03 30 00 38 00 40 00 48 00 12 0F 33 35 37 37 39 36 31 30 31 36 31 34 33 31 33 18 C2 EE CE D1 CB 2E",
    "server_ts": 1603180834000,
    "ts": 1603180834000
}
```

cURL:

```
curl -X PUT "es1:9200/staging-devices-2020-10-20/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "imei": "24779610124313",
  "json": "{\"imei\":\"357796101614313\",\"ts\":1603180834000,\"values\":{\"coreMsgId\":2810,\"obdIt\":{\"distance\":0,\"distanceCombustion\":0,\"idleTime\":0,\"idleTimeCombustion\":0,\"maxSpeed\":0,\"totalEnergyCons\":0,\"totalFuelCons\":0,\"totalTime\":488,\"totalTimeCombustion\":0}}}",
  "raw": "04 00 00 32 0A 18 08 FA 15 32 13 08 00 10 00 18 00 20 00 28 E8 03 30 00 38 00 40 00 48 00 12 0F 33 35 37 37 39 36 31 30 31 36 31 34 33 31 33 18 C2 EE CE D1 CB 2E",
  "server_ts": 1603180834000,
  "ts": 1603180834000
}
'
```

Comment: Yes it is. You can't create your own type (values) like you did in older versions. In 7.x it is _doc. and that is the way to insert documents, the one I use. Try it and let me know if you are still having problems.

Comment: I got this... ```{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason": "Invalid index name [_doc], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "_doc"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason": "Invalid index name [_doc], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
    "index_uuid": "_na_",
    "index": "_doc"
  },
  "status": 400
}```

Comment: Hi, If my answer helped you. Please feel free to accept/upvote. Thanks